# Ionic List populate data from Sqlite

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am building an mobile application using Ionic and [Sqlite](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage).I am successful in storing data to the Sqlite database, retrieving the data back from the database and printing it to the console. Now, I am unable to figure out how to populate the data form the database in an ionic list

```
$scope.load = function() {

     $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'SELECT * FROM cart ORDER BY id DESC')
     .then(
         function(res) {
              if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                  for (var i=0; i<res.rows.length; i++) {
                     console.log("Product ID: " + res.rows.item(i).productID + " Product Name : " + res.rows.item(i).productName);
                  }
               }
          },
          function(error) {
               console.log("Error on loading: " + error.message);
          }
       );
    }
```

**I need to display res.rows.item(i).productID & res.rows.item(i).productName in an ionic list**.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer my own question...it turns out to be actually very simple.It just works as normally as other Angularjs arrays. Made the following changes to my code:

```
$scope.load = function() {

     $scope.listItems= [];

     $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'SELECT * FROM cart ORDER BY id DESC')
     .then(
         function(res) {
              if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                  for (var i=0; i<res.rows.length; i++) {
                     console.log("Product ID: " + res.rows.item(i).productID + " Product Name : " + res.rows.item(i).productName);
                     $scope.listItems.push(res.rows.item(i));
                  }
               }
          },
          function(error) {
               console.log("Error on loading: " + error.message);
          }
       );
    }
```

Now you can use ng-repeat or any other ionic element any display the data from sqlite as {{listItems}}.